# The list does not come up (ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: asp.net-core, listview, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Thanks for helping me. Sorry for long description... I try to be detailed

This is my `ProcessController`:

```
namespace MVCDemo.Controllers
{
    public class ProcessController : Controller
    {
        // GET Process
        public ViewResult List()
        {
            var processList = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                              select p;
            ViewData.Model = processList.ToList();
            return View();
        }

        // GET Process/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var process = (from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                           where p.Id == id
                           select p).Single();
            return View(process);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `Details.cshtml` view:

```
@this.Model.ProcessName <br />
@this.Model.Id
```

This is my `List.cshtml` view:

```
<div>
    <h1>List</h1>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var process in this.Model)
        {
            <li> 
                @Html.ActionLink("process.ProcessName", "Details", new { id = process.Id })
            </li>
        }
    </ul> 
</div>
```

My problem is that every line I only can see "process.ProcessName" instead of a list what I would see if my `List.cshtml` would look this way:

```
<div>
    <h1>List</h1>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var process in this.Model)
        {
            <li>
                @process.ProcessName
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can see the problem is probably with this line

```
 @Html.ActionLink("process.ProcessName", "Details", new { id = process.Id })
```

But I don't know how to change the `process.ProcessName` to get the list and then I can click on. If I change it this way this just does not work out. Then the whole line does not run.

```
<div>
    <h1>List</h1>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var process in this.Model)
        {
            <li> 
                @Html.ActionLink(@process.ProcessName, "Details", new { id = process.Id })
            </li>
        }
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the list is stored in the VewData object while in the foreach loop use the Model object.

The following code appears to be working

ProcessController:

```
namespace MVCDemo.Controllers
{
    public class ProcessController : Controller
    {
        // GET Process
        public ViewResult List()
        {
            var processList = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                              select p;
                              
            return View(processList.ToList());
        }

        // GET Process/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var process = (from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                           where p.Id == id
                           select p).Single();
            return View(process);
        }
    }
}
```

List.cshtml view:

```
@model List<process>

<div>
    <h1>List</h1>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var process in this.Model)
        {
            <li> 
                @Html.ActionLink(process.ProcessName, "Details", new { id = process.Id })
            </li>
        }
    </ul> 
</div>
```